# Software to extract data from pictures into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-extraction, object-recognition

I would like to take pictures of codes or numbers imprinted on products and then insert these strings into one Excel-spreadsheet. Ideally, the strings of multiple pictures could be pasted into different cells of the same Excel-sheet. Generally, this feature seems to be embedded in the mobile version of Excel. However, the quality of that output does not work in my use-case (e.g. Excel will only manage if the characters are clear and with a strong contrast. As soon as it is not black on white, or not from a plane surface or not with homogenuous lighting, it will struggle.)

Thanks!

Comment: What platform? This is built into macOS & iOS.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in Windows.